# Wait for AudioClip finish before destroy Object

Tags: unity, audio

If I Play the gun sound on my "bullet" object, how can I prevent the end of Audio sound if the bullet hit something so it destroy. 
To clarify:

Bullet prefab -> Audio Source -> Audio Clip = MachineGun.mp3
PlayOnAwake = true

When I instantiate bullet, MachineGun AudioClip is played. 
But the bullet is fast and hit something before the clip is end. 
This Kill the machine audio effect making it irrealistic.

How can I tell Unity "Play the sound to the end, despite the object is destroyed".

I've tried

Destroy(gameObject, AudioClip.length)

But it seems not works

Comment: I would probably go with a singleton type audio manager and use events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html), this will create a new audiosource for the clip at the given position and then automatically clean up after the playback is complete.